# cant get profile images to display with django

Tags: python, django

I am working through a basic django upload image tutorial and I have become stuck. I am trying to let a user upload a file, store it in in a folder, and then save the address to that image in the db. This part all seems to be working. Then I try and have a simple page to display all images to make sure its working and the img tag in the HTML keeps having a src of "unknown". I am unsure of what exactly the problem is because there are no errors thrown anywhere.

**Views.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .models import UserProfile


# Create your views here.


class CreateProfileView(CreateView):
    template_name = "profiles/create_profile.html"
    model = UserProfile
    fields = "__all__"
    success_url = "/profiles"
    
class ProfilesView(ListView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = "profiles/user-profiles.html"
    context_object_name = "profiles"
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image")
```

**User-Profiles.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User Profiles</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for profile in profiles %}
        <li>
            <img src="{{ profile.url }}">
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms 

class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    user_image = forms.ImageField()
```

**Urls.py in /profiles**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CreateProfileView.as_view()),
    path("list", views.ProfilesView.as_view())
]
```

**Urls.py in project folder**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("reviews.urls")),
    path("profiles/", include("profiles.urls"))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for feedback project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure--#-h(v7)m6p4rr&fs#7&caa9!$w4!#xzhkioljoy34v3@o!%@%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'reviews',
    'profiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'feedback.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'feedback.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

#path for files to be stored
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "uploads"
MEDIA_URL = BASE_DIR = "/user-image/" #you can define the URL to whatever you want between '/ /'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `.url` of the `.image` field so:

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    <li>
        <img src="{{ profile.image.url }}">
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```